# Values from for loop appear as NaN from time to time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nan

I have for loop that iterates list of html audio elements and is meant to display their total times. The values randomly appear as NaN upon refreshing the page. Sometimes one two of them, sometimes all of them, sometimes none of them and so on.I tried to make it as function that runs once the window is loaded, I also tried with document on load. Finally I left it out of any function and the result is the same. Here's my code:

```
let totalDurationMinutes = 0;
let totalDurationSeconds = 0;

for (i=0; i<playList.length; i++) {


let newP = document.createElement('p');
totalDurationMinutes = Math.floor(playList[i].duration/60);
totalDurationSeconds = Math.ceil(playList[i].duration%60);


if(totalDurationMinutes<10){
totalDurationMinutes = "0" + totalDurationMinutes;
}

if(totalDurationSeconds<10){
totalDurationSeconds = "0" + totalDurationSeconds;
}


newP.className = "totalDuration";
newP.innerHTML = totalDurationMinutes + ":" + totalDurationSeconds;
playList[i].parentElement.appendChild(newP);
}
```

Edit: Another thing I forgot to mention is that if I put the code inside a function and trigger it on click, everything goes perfect, but outside function or function on window load, causes the above mentioned issue.

Comment: what is `playList` - without its content everything is assumption

Comment: Html audio elements. In addition these audio elements are placed inside <li>s

Comment: You are adding string and integers, you should be using 0 instead of "0", see if that works

Comment: Thanks but I already tried to completely remove the ifs and it still occurs, also forgot to mention that I cleared the cache of the browser and it didn't help.

Comment: By your code seems like the `playList` has some problems. Try `parseInt(playList[i].duration, 10)` to see if you get any error.

Comment: How sure are you that `playList[i].duration` is **always** a number? Is it ever empty/null/some other non-numeric value?

Comment: Good question. According to typeof it is number every time but your answer gave me another idea: I tried to see the type of totalDurationMinutes after the if statements and it returns string to the values with NaN and number to the one that show the actual total time of the respective track. This might help us resolve the issue.

Comment: @supra28 it is used to add a leading zero with the number is smaller than 10, so that `2` will be shown as `02`, so `"0" +` is correct.

Comment: @user6860273  `NaN` is a state of a number like `Inf` and `-Inf`, so the type of `NaN` is still number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out some kind of solution. Since on click the function is executed properly and on load not always, I figured that the document might not be completely loaded when the function is being executed, therefore I just used setTimeout with value 1800. I tried with smaller values but it fails from time to time, but less than before. So it will work fine if your internet connection is good. If someone else comes up with better, 100% working solution, I will be glad to hear it. Here's my code now:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setTimeout(function (){

let totalDurationMinutes = 0;
let totalDurationSeconds = 0;

for (i=0; i<playList.length; i++) {


let newP = document.createElement('p');
totalDurationMinutes = Math.floor(playList[i].duration/60);
totalDurationSeconds = Math.ceil(playList[i].duration%60);


if(totalDurationMinutes<10){
  totalDurationMinutes = "0" + totalDurationMinutes;
}

if(totalDurationSeconds<10){
  totalDurationSeconds = "0" + totalDurationSeconds;
}


newP.className = "totalDuration";
newP.innerHTML = totalDurationMinutes + ":" + totalDurationSeconds;
playList[i].parentElement.appendChild(newP);

}

},1800));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always a chance that you are getting non-numeric data and you should cater for that.

Try something like the following using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check for numeracy:

```
let totalDurationMinutes = 0;
let totalDurationSeconds = 0;

for (i=0; i<playList.length; i++) {


  let newP = document.createElement('p');

  if(isNan(playList[i])){ //Bascic numeric test
     newP.innerHTML = "Duration not numeric: " + playList[i];
  }else{ 
     totalDurationMinutes = Math.floor(playList[i].duration/60);
     totalDurationSeconds = Math.ceil(playList[i].duration%60);    

     if(totalDurationMinutes<10){
        totalDurationMinutes = "0" + totalDurationMinutes;
     }

     if(totalDurationSeconds<10){
        totalDurationSeconds = "0" + totalDurationSeconds;
     }    

     newP.className = "totalDuration";
     newP.innerHTML = totalDurationMinutes + ":" + totalDurationSeconds;
     playList[i].parentElement.appendChild(newP);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to see the total duration every time. From what I understand, this will replace the NaN value in the html with string and the value of playList[i].

Answer (score -1):

try change

```
if(totalDurationMinutes<10){
totalDurationMinutes = "0" + totalDurationMinutes;
}

if(totalDurationSeconds<10){
totalDurationSeconds = "0" + totalDurationSeconds;
}
```

with this

```
if(totalDurationMinutes<10){
totalDurationMinutes = 0 + totalDurationMinutes;
}

if(totalDurationSeconds<10){
totalDurationSeconds = 0 + totalDurationSeconds;
}
```

string "0" with number 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried this and it didn't work. I also tried to completely remove these if statements and still not working.

Comment: I am interested, maybe you can simplify your question so it can be directly to the question, or all the code, to know more about the plot of the story

Comment: the `"0" + totalDurationMinutes` is used to add a leading zero to the number in case it is smaller than `10`, changing `"0"` to a number would break that functionality.  And it would not change anything if one of the numbers is `NaN`